# Правильно составлен cron?

Tags: cron, веб-программирование, php, linux, сервер

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно, чтобы крон срабатывал каждое воскресение в 4 утра. 
Правильно ли я составил крон?

```
0 4 * * 7
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Настроил правильно.

Если у тебя выделенный или виртуальный сервер — советую использовать Webmin. Там все наглядно по многим вопросам управления сервером, в т. ч. и крон (хоть тру-админы и ругаются, но это из идеологических соображений))